# Who was Shukracharya's mother?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, shukracharya, matsya-purana, bhrigu

We know that Shukracharya's mother was slain by Vishnu on behest of Indra.
Matsya Purana claims it was Khyati. And then Bhrigu cursed Vishnu to be born 7 times.

But Srimad Bhagvatam (4.1.43 to 4.1.45) has Khyati as his great-great grandmother.

Is this another instance of contradiction between texts or is there an explanation?

Comment: According to Devi Bhagavatam, the mother of Sukra was Kavya Usana (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kavyamata).  However, according to Rig Veda, Kavya Usana was a poet/seer.  It is very difficult to reconcile different texts of Hinduism.@Carmen sandiego

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Devi Bhagavatam is not a valid scripture though; it is neither a Purana nor an Upapurana.